# Textarea formats does not indent first line

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling with strange behavior of textarea... I am writing small snippet store for my own needs and I would like to paste a code fragment into textarea and then format it using jQuery library, but sometimes I get very strange output (jQuery library is turned off). Screenshot shows it all:
[image]

In notepad it looks the way I want it, but in `pre` tag first line is not indented... Could you explain me why? I am using Ruby and Ruby on Rails if it matters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're populating the textarea from RoR, right?

I don't suppose it's as simple as your <% %> being on a new line, and then your code indenting adding extra spaces in?

Comment: ehh... so silly mistake... :) Could you tell me how can I avoid such situations using HAML?

Comment: Ummmm, no. Never used HAML. By the looks of it, it's something that HAML would have to address in their output - rather than you in your input to HAML. Good luck :)